# Как разделить массив на значения?

Tags: java, массивы

Приветствую.
Существует динамичный массив (количество значений всегда разное). Значения в нем выглядят примерно таким образом:

```
[
1-Vas-12-Hello,
2-Tes-13-World,
3-Mek-13-Leon,
4-Sec-15-Mih
]
```

Нужно: разбить массив на значения, а сами значения разрезать на массив по символу (-).
Разделение массива for и деление строки Split не дают нужного результата. На выходе получаю только одну разделенную строку. Кто может помочь с правильным кодом? Я даже не знаю, как это правильно сделать... Вот [Код попытки](http://pastebin.com/U7C1wvyt). Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String tempArray = temp[t].split("-"); //- почему здесь строка?

```
    String[] temp = new String[]{ "1-Vas-12-Hello", "2-Tes-13-World",
    "3-Mek-13-Leon", "4-Sec-15-Mih"};
    List list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String sT:temp){
        String[] tempArray = sT.split("-");
        for(String sA:tempArray)
            list.add(sA);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, list вернул все значения через запятую. Но можно ли сделать как-нибудь этот массив так, чтобы я обращался к нему через переменную
и в таком виде [0] => ([0] => '1', [1] => 'Vas' [2] => '12' [3] => 'Hello') [1] => ... Моя задача иметь доступ к каждому элементу в пределах от 0 до 3 каждого массива. Благодарю

Comment: вроде нужно обращаться через двойные скобки после разбивания на символы строки.
`String []sub=new String[yourstr.length()+1];while(yourstr.length() > 1){sub[sub.length-yourstr.length()-1]=yourstr.substring(0, 0);yourstr=yourstr.substring(1);}`
Если делать вручную, есть стандартная функция String.LastPointOf(строка) возвращающая позицию первого символа этого выражения, если находит и -1 если нет. после через String.substring(int start_index, int end_index) разрезать строку на части, выбирая разделитель.

Comment: Ну, если вы хотели массив массивов - можно было просто добавлять весь 

            String[] temp = new String[]{ "1-Vas-12-Hello",
            "2-Tes-13-World", "3-Mek-13-Leon", "4-Sec-15-Mih"};
            List list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String sT:temp){
                list.add(sT.split("-"));
            }
            System.out.println(((String[])list.get(0))[2]);

Получаете первый элемент списка - 0й индекс.

Преобразуете тип в String[]. Так как метод списка get вернет Object

Обращаетесь к 3му элементу массива - 2й индекс

Выведет 12

Comment: О спасибо вам большое. Теперь я циклом получаю только нужные мне элементы и вывожу их. Спасибо, выручили. Всем спасибо за ответы и советы.

Answer (score 0):

stringtokenizer специально заточеный класс

Comment: А какие есть плюсы по сравнению с подходом ТСа?

Насколько я понимаю, при использовании объекта класса StringTokenizer придется склеивать полученные подстроки в массив. Да и конструкции будут аналогичными. Не говоря о том, что придется каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр класса с передачей в качестве параметров входной строки и разделителя.

Я просто не шибко шарю, хочу понять, чего не догоняю.